# Forum responses to topics do not show up

Tags: php, html, forums

I am very new to coding PHP, HTML, and CSS and am just making a basic website with very basic functions that I will change and make better as I learn more about how to code these languages. My question is why my responses to a thread I have created in my forum response page does not appear when I view the forum? The code I used was not mine - I got it from 
this website :www.phpgang.com/create-a-simple-forum-in-php_158.html

Everything else with this code works, no errors, and I can create a topic, view the topic, and respond to the topic but the response does not appear when I view the topic. It does however add a comment to the comment area of the forum table that shows all of the current topics. Please offer any ideas of how I can make the response display. If you have any questions on what exactly it is doing please comment.

(the code that is supposed to display and add the response to the topic) 
add_answer.php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="greatdebate"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="fanswers"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databsae.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get value of id that sent from hidden field 
$id=$_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number. 
$sql="SELECT MAX(a_id) AS Maxa_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no
       answer yet set it = 1 
if ($rows) {
$Max_id = $rows['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
$Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form 
$a_name=$_POST['a_name'];
$a_email=$_POST['a_email'];
$a_answer=$_POST['a_answer']; 

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

// Insert answer 
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(question_id, a_id, a_name, a_email, a_answer,          
a_datetime)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$a_name', '$a_email', '$a_answer', '$datetime')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";

// If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column 
$tbl_name2="fquestions";
$sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
// Close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Please contact me if you need to see the main_forum.php or the new_topic.php,

Comment: Would you copy in the relevant part of the code? If your link breaks, the question has no future value, which is why we like questions to be (mostly) self-contained. Also, if you can do some initial debugging (i.e. try to narrow down the failure point) then that would help guide readers to offering relevant answers.

Comment: If you're learning, you might look into a different tutorial.  The mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should look into mysqli or PDO.  The code here is wide open to an sql injection attack.  Remeber [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).  As to the question, is the `$id` getting posted correctly?

Comment: My goal is not to make something that is protected from sql injection attacks. I just need it to work. Protecting my code comes second. If any of you had a tutorial of how to make a forum for me to follow that is better than the one I used please post it I am open to starting over.

Comment: The line containing `answer yet set it = 1` is probably meant to be a comment, but looks like it would cause a fatal error. Prefix it with `//`.